# Different ways of adding a library to my HTML

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any important difference between using the following code:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

or just adding a library with the script tag (the following code):

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.js"><\/script>
```

to add a library to an HTML?

Comment: If you own the page, why do you need to check for window.jQuery in the first place? You should know in advance whether the library is included or not.

Comment: @Icarus -- Its a technique for handling fallback if jQuery doesn't load from a CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

is plain bad. You should not really use `document.write` to include scripts and styles. All javascript code is loaded onto the document at the time the web page is loaded. Since you might just be executing document.write after the page is loaded, it might just not work.

the standard way to include javascript is the second one:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way to add a library, like jQuery for example, is downloading the library and adding the following code...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-library/library.js"></script>
```

:)